# Blender Object disappears when object is too far from the camera

Tags: blender

I use Blender only recently and have the problem that objects slowly disappearing when they move too far from my point of view, as you can see on the image.
[image: Img_with_error]

Comment: You might get a better response on our sister site [blender.se]

Answer (score 1):

Play around with the Clipping in the "VIEW" section  (3d View -> press <kbd>N</kbd> -> "VIEW" section). (Bottom right corner of your screenshot)

Increasing the CLIP END value should do the job.

With the Clipping settings, you can also "cut yourself" into objects from the front (increase/decrease the CLIP START value) and see the inside. That can be very handy for weightpainting, or selecting faces in general.

Answer (score 0):

[Objects disappear when looking through camera view in Blender](https://youtu.be/Wk706Oj4Co8)

While setting up my camera with the camera lock to view option selected, I noticed that on switching on to the camera view, the object had disappeared.

I tried zooming in and out, but that did not work. I exited the camera view and then selected the object in the outliner and then tried zooming in and out and then panning down and adjusting the view in the view port.  I could see that the object was now visible and that the camera was positioned below the object. That was because the camera was added wrt to the position of the cursor which was snapped to the world origin. I a sure many would have encountered such issues.

I then selected the camera to ascertain its position. Then by using the grab tool, I moved the camera along the Z axis just above the object and then switched to the camera view and selected the lock camera to
view option to adjust the camera view to the desired position.

This helped me locate my object in the camera view. Do let me know in the comments if there are other ways of dealing with this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).